# Show that the randomized test is uniformly most powerful

Tags: probability-distributions, solution-verification, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be iid random sample from $U(0,\theta)$ for $\theta>0$. Consider testing the null hypothesis $H_0:\theta\leq1$ vs the alternative hypothesis $H_A:\theta>1$ at level $\alpha$. Show that the following randomized test is uniformly most powerful
$$
T(X)=
\begin{cases}
1,&\;\;X_{(n)}\geq1\\
\alpha,&\;\;X_{(n)}<1
\end{cases}
$$

---

The CDF of $X_{(n)}$ is $F(x)=\left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^n$. The power function I have for this test is
$$
\beta(\theta)=
\begin{cases}
\alpha\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right)^n+1-\frac{1}{\theta^n}&\;\;\theta>1\\
\alpha\left(\frac{\alpha}{\theta}\right)^n&\;\;\theta\leq1
\end{cases}
$$

I am not sure how show this is UMP.

Comment: Should some of the $X_n$ be $X_{(n)}:=\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$?

Comment: @angryavian yes